# Is there anyway to style the embed media of spotify via css or jquery?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, iframe

I'm creating a podcast website and like to embed the spotify player. The style that I want is just for the player to have the play icon, nothing else. Is it possible if I'll embed the spotify player on my wordpress website, then style it via css or jquery?

Comment: You should improve your question. https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

You can check this link [enter link description here](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/products/product-media/add-media) for Adding product media and for video please refer to this link [enter link description here](https://getshogun.com/learn/shopify-insert-video)